# I need to find Then orthogonal projection of

Tags: linear-algebra

$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\1 & 2\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}$,let $V$ be the vector space generated by collumn vector of $A$, I need to find Then orthogonal projection of $(0 1 0)^t$ on $V$.

I just do not understand the question.

could any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to project the vector $(0,1,0)^t$ onto the plane spanned by $(1,1,1)^t$ and $(-1,2,-1)^t$.

Since $(1,1,1)^t$ and $(-1,2,-1)^t$ are orthogonal, the projection is the sum of the [vector projections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection) of $(0,1,0)^t$ onto $(1,1,1)^t$ and $(0,1,0)^t$ onto $(-1,2,-1)^t$.

---

Alternatively, you could project the vector $(0,1,0)^t$ onto a vector normal to the plane, then subtract the result from $(0,1,0)^t$.

Answer (score 1):

To make $A$ into an orthonormal set of columns, the two columns are already orthogonal so you just need to divide by the norms, giving the two columns as $(1/\sqrt{3},1/\sqrt{3},1/\sqrt{3})^t$ and $(-1/\sqrt{6},2/\sqrt{6},-1/\sqrt{6})^t$.  Now, with $A$ as these 2 columns, there is a theorem that says that for any matrix $A$, if the columns of $A$ are orthonormal, then the matrix giving the projection onto $V$ is $P=AA^t$, where $V$ is the span of the columns of $A$. (This is also easy to see by thinking about what $AA^t$ means). This projection matrix $P$ will orthogonally project any vector you want onto $V$, including your desired $(0,1,0)^t$.